# Is PersistStateMachineHandler in spring-statemachine-recipes thread safe?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-statemachine

I decleared `PersistStateMachineHandler` as a field in `@Component` Class in Spring Boot project. Which means method of class could be call concurrently.

However I found [`PersistStateMachineHandler#handleEventWithState`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/3c38675eb031bc094602a9181d2c1f8074d2b4dc/spring-statemachine-recipes/src/main/java/org/springframework/statemachine/recipes/persist/PersistStateMachineHandler.java#L71-L79) or newer [`PersistStateMachineHandler#handleEventWithStateReactively`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/3c38675eb031bc094602a9181d2c1f8074d2b4dc/spring-statemachine-recipes/src/main/java/org/springframework/statemachine/recipes/persist/PersistStateMachineHandler.java#L88-L100) stop, set state, then restart the state machine without any synchronization/locks. Is this method thread safe?

Comment: Looks like the was a pull request about locking https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/pull/813 and it was accepted. So i think it should work.

Comment: @Alex Adding a redis lock seems too heavy for my simple usage. I think the point is made `PersistStateMachineHandler#handleEventWithState` thread safe to avoid setting wrong state when it runs concurrently? Can I announce the state machine of handler as `ThreadLocal` or something else to provide thread safe feature?